# How to read and open all notification in Android?

Tags: android

I have an app which reads all notification comes in device then stores that notification in `Activity` contain `ListView` and after that remove that notification from status bar. To do this I have used "`NotificationListenerService`".

When I click `ListView` that contain notification I want to open that notification in their target application. How do I do that?

Code I used:

```
public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
    Log.i("Msg", "Notification Posted");
    String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
    String ticker = "";
    if (sbn.getNotification().tickerText != null) {
        ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
    }
    Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
    String title = extras.getString("android.title");
    String text = null;
    if (extras.getCharSequence("android.text") != null) {
        text = extras.getCharSequence("android.text").toString();
    }
    Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;
    ;
    if (id != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    }

    String jsonData = sharedPreference.getAppsArrayListData();
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<WhiteListModel>>() {
    }.getType();
    whiteListModels = gson.fromJson(jsonData, type);

    if (whiteListModels != null && whiteListModels.size() > 0)
    //loop to insert notification data into db.
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < whiteListModels.size(); i++) {
            model = whiteListModels.get(i);
            if (pack.equals(model.getPackName())) {
                dbHelper.insertNotification(title, pack, text, byteArray);
            }
        }

        //loop to remove notification from status bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < whiteListModels.size(); i++) {
            model = whiteListModels.get(i);
            if (pack.equals(model.getPackName())) {
                NotificationService.this.cancelNotification(sbn.getKey());
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check out this [link](https://github.com/kpbird/NotificationListenerService-Example) , But i have used it so am not sure it work for you or not but as per description it provide

- getId
- getNotification
- getPackageName
- getPostTime

from above you can use **getPackageName** to open target application

Comment: I want to open notification page in target application

Comment: I don't think it's possible

Comment: How you find that wich activity , fragment or anything else thay are using for showing notification.